# Track a non-generic badge's progress (aka tag-badge)

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

Is it possible to set "Next badge" in the profile to be a badge that is not listed? https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/c-sharp; specifically.

I tried searching for it in the fancy pop-up textbox in all of its variations but to no avail. I'm looking to track my progress in that badge specifically.

Edit: No synonyms found (c#, c-sharp, sharp, #)

[image]

[image]

Comment: BTW is this really a feature-request? I didn't change the tags since you might want such a feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You **can** track tag badges but you do it in the space where the privileges are tracked, not where the main badges are tracked.

There is a nifty little settings panel accessed by clicking on the cog next to the Next Privilege section:

[image]

Additionally, as you see here, the tag badges replace the "Next privilege" section entirely, once you have unlocked all privileges:

[image: Privileges]

Comment: That's the explanation I was looking for! 
Hope you don't mind the edit I introduced. Will not post it as answer myself as it was your answer that guided me there, thanks.

Comment: @ИвоНедев No problem! I learned something new, too! I've incorporated it more cleanly.